# Looping over strings gives wrong type argument error in Emacs Lisp

Tags: list, emacs, lisp, elisp, quote

I am trying to loop over a list of strings with `dolist`, and join element with a prefix string, using `string-join` from `subr-x` to create new string.

```
(dolist (p '("a" "b" "c"))
   (string-join '(p ".rnc")))
```

I am getting the error `Wrong type argument: sequencep, p`. The following code however works.

```
(dolist (p '("a" "b" "c"))
   (print p))
```

So this seems to be a problem of `string-join` or equivalently `mapconcat` within a loop. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: There's nothing specific to Emacs Lisp here. It's about understanding **Lisp** `quote`, evaluation, and list structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> '(p ".rnc")
> ```

It's very important to understand that `'...` which means `(quote ...)` is not a shorthand for making lists.

It's a form which causes lisp to return, unevaluated, the object that was created by the lisp reader.

In this instance the lisp reader returns a list containing the symbol `p` and a string `".rnc"` -- and the symbol `p` is indeed not a sequence (hence your error).

Use `(list p ".rnc")` to create a list using the *evaluated* value of `p` as a variable.

---

p.s. Be sure to go over the distinct `read` and `eval` phases of lisp execution.  Once you understand the distinction, `quote` will make much more sense.

Answer (score 2):

`string-join` takes a sequence of strings and joins them together with the separator, so even if the arguments were correct, it's not going to do what you want if you pass it just a single string and a separator, since in that case it just returns the string because there's nothing to join. Also, `dolist` will by default return `nil`, and it makes collecting your results more difficult than necessary.

Use `mapcar` instead, since it will return a list of results, and use `concat` to add the suffix:

```
(mapcar (lambda (s) (concat s ".rnc")) '("a" "b" "c"))
```

Evaluating this results in:

```
("a.rnc" "b.rnc" "c.rnc")
```

Comment: @phils answer solves my problem, but this gives a better way to do what I was trying to do.